# Differential area for sector of a circle

Tags: integration, derivatives, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

While studying isoperimetric problems, I ran into a solution using a differential area element based on the area of a circle sector:
$$A_{sector}=\frac{1}{2}r^{2}\theta$$
for radius $r$ & angle $\theta$ subtended by the arc. The solution I saw took $r=r(\theta)$, and defined the differential area as:

$$dA=\frac{1}{2}r(\theta)^2d\theta$$
I'm confused as to how the author of the solution arrived at that definition, as I can't see a way that taking the derivative of the original area definition could produce the latter.

Comment: Since $dA$ generally denotes an area form (a $2$-form, such as $r\, dr\, d\theta$ in polar coordinates) while $\frac{1}{2}r^{2}\, d\theta$ is a $1$-form, it's hard to know what was intended. Offhand I suspect a typo; for example, $r\, dr\, d\theta = d(\frac{1}{2}r^{2})\, d\theta$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}r^2(\theta)d\theta$ is the appropriate thing to integrate $\int\limits_a^b$ to find the area of a sector of a polar curve $r(\theta)$ subtended between $\theta=a$ and $\theta=b$. Presumably they are using the first equation within a 'small' $\theta$ and approximating the infinitesimal wedge area by a circular sector